# Search and replace with a batch file

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I am writing a batch file script using Windows command and want to change each occurrence of some blank space with ","  What is the simplest way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your users are a list of words on one line in a text file, separated by spaces, eg:

```
one two three four
```

Create a batch file SpaceToComma.bat as follows:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /F "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (%1) do @set data=%%a
echo %data: =,%
endlocal
```

Then run it, you'll get the words separated by commas. Is this what you want?

```
C:\>SpaceToComma.bat data.txt
one,two,three,four
```

If you have a multi-line file, then this will do it:

data.txt

```
one two three four
five six seven
```

SpaceToComma.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /F "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (%1) do @call :processaline %%a
endlocal
goto :eof
:processaline
setlocal
set data=%*
echo %data: =,%
endlocal
goto:eof
```

Output

```
C:\>SpaceToComma.bat data.txt
one,two,three,four
five,six,seven
```

(There's probably a clever way of doing this without the subroutine, using the !data! syntax for delayed variable expansion, but I couldn't get it to work with the substitution syntax.)

If this is not what you want, then please explain and I can try to help.

(PS: I delight in using batch files where people insist it can't be done.)

Comment: Thanks PA. Answer corrected. (Nice to see someone read it that carefully.)

Comment: @RichardA I used SpaceToComma.bat in a 2GB csv file and worked fine. However, for each space it puts a comma, i. e., 2014  12  1 became  2014,,12,,1. Is there a way to recognize various spaces and replace with just one comma? (for example, from 2014  12  1 to  2014,12,1).

Answer (score 1):

You could download sed.exe from http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ and run this command:

```
sed -e "s/ /,/" infile.txt >outfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it will depend a lot on how you are getting the data, but you may be able to finagle something with a For-Do construct. Make the field seperator be a space then build the string back in the do with a , between each token. Might I suggest a more robust scripting language? You should have VBScript on just about any relatively modern windows bow.